# Apache Camel : Cannot locate xsd file exception

Tags: java, spring, xsd, apache-camel

I have following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
                           http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd 
                           http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.9.0.xsd
 ">
```

Whenever I start my web application, it gives me following error:

```
Apr 19, 2012 3:10:59 PM org.springframework.util.xml.SimpleSaxErrorHandler warning
WARNING: Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.9.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaWarning(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4323)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4780)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:988)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:988)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:585)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:415)
Apr 19, 2012 3:10:59 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 81 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/Beans.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'camelContext'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at .....
```

I do not understand why this happens. Also if this is due to some Internet connectivity issues, why don't I get a cxf xsd exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first explanation isn't pertinent, because the .xsd exists here:

http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.9.0.xsd

Check your XML document.  It's got another issue.

Posting that entire stack trace is thorough but unnecessary.

Comment: i have edited my question... i ll post the part where i am using camel also.

Comment: <camelContext id="camelcontext-1" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
   <from>
    direct:start
   </from>
   <to>
    http://localhost:foo/bar   </to>
  </route>

 </camelContext>

Comment: Resolved the error.. the namespace that i am using in the camelContext was missing "/" after sping. also my classpath had some exporting sort of problem with camel-spring2.9.0 jar. Now atleast i am able to start my application though new exceptions are coming..  :)

Comment: Will you please post your solution?  I don't understand what "/" you are referring to.I'm getting the same exception but the xsd I'm pointing to has camelContext.

Answer (score 0):

The XSD are provided in the dependencies. You should verify your classpath, you need to have version 2.9. You could also use the generic location in order to get the one available:

```
http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
```

Comment: i have this already.. this was my original config.. i thought i would be needing specific version.. but it gives same error. i am using camel 2.9.0 and i already have camel-spring2.9.0 jar in buildpath..  http://camel.apache.org/xml-reference.html